# Lin Alg 100-Level Recursion Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, recursion

I want to pave a $2\times n$ rectangle with $1\times 2$ blocks which come in two colours, white and grey. Let $w_n$ be the number of different ways this can be done.

I determined the recursive equation: $w_n = 2w_{n-1} + 4w_{n-2}$

But I'm having difficulties solving the recursive equation.

I've gathered that the roots of the equation are $(2±\sqrt{ 20})/2$ which I've equated to $(\phi + 1)$ and $(1 - \phi \text{ or } 2\sigma)$ (golden ratio related symbols) respectively (I may be wrong at this point). and I've tried to solve for $w_n$ using a linear approach. My final equation is:
$$ w_n = \sigma^2 (\phi+1)^n + \sigma(1-\phi)^n $$
however it doesn't work.

Comment: The general solution is $A(1+\sqrt{5})^n +B(1-\sqrt{5})^n$. To find $A$ and $B$, determine $w_1$ and $w_2$, or, better, $w_0$ and $w_1$, by explicit enumeration.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your help and cool name btw!
Basically, you're saying my roots are wrong? And that they are 1+√5 and 1-√5. How exactly did you find that? I think I can figure out the rest after this part

Comment: The characteristic equation is $x^2-2x-4=0$. By the Quadratic Formula, the roots are $\frac{2\pm\sqrt{20}}{2}$, which simplifies to $1\pm\sqrt{5}$.  Note by the way that the approach bby Modded Bear (colour later) is more efficient in its recycling of old results. (More)

Comment: Alternately, we can let $w_k=2^ky_k$ and obtain the recurrence $y_n=y_{n-1}+y_{n-2}$, familiar.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, I actually see now, your 1+√5 is actually the same as my ϕ+1. The problem then must lie in my subsequent explicit enumeration as you called it..

Comment: It is clear that $w_1=2$. You can find $w_2$ easily enough, but a sneaky person would observe that $w_0=1$, there is $1$ way to tile the $2\times 0$ rectangle, do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u_n$ be the number of ways to pave a board of $2\times n$ using blocks of size $2\times n$ which come in one color. Clearly $u_1=1$ and $u_2=2$. From here on we prove $u_{n+2}=u_n+u_{n+1}$. To prove this look at the right edge of the board. You can fill the two squares on that edge in two ways. If you fill with a vertical block you can fill the other squares in $u_{n+1}$ ways, if you fill with two horizontal blocks you can fill the other squares in $u_{n}$ ways. Obtaining the recursion.

This tells us $u_n$ is fibonacci.

We can now modify this to accept blocks of various colors. You can first place the blocks in $u_n$ ways, since there are $n$ blocks we can color them in $2^n$ ways. Telling us $w_n=2^n u_n$. The formula for the fibonaccis is well know.